# Jenkins Job parameters

Tags: jenkins, parameters, salesforce

I'm using a jenkins job to retrieve data from Salesforce and I have too many parameters (such as connection to salesforce and so on..)
I want to have a file parameter for my jobs instead of entering them manually, but I can't find an example of a file.
is there a specific extension or a specific structure like an xml file?

PS: I don't use a local jenkins but a kind of entreprise edition.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Jenkins script file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can utilize `Prepare an environment for the run` to specify a plain file which is relative to your job workspace as below:

[image]

In this plain file, you can pre-define job parameters in Java Propertier file format:
AA=xxx
BB=yyy

They will all be injected as Environment Variable, you can refer any param by `${AA}` in Linux shell, or `%AA%` in Windows batch. If param value has space, use double quote like `"${AA}"` or `"%AA%"`